# How to create a pubsub topic within firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create topics via firebase cloud functions. I have created this, which does seem to work:

```
const init = () => {
    const topicName = "check-in-order";
  pubsub
    .createTopic(topicName)
    .then(results => {
      const topic = results[0];
            console.log(`Topic ${topicName} created.`);
            return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
            console.error("ERROR on init:", err);
            return;
    });
};

init()
```

but that obviously runs every time. While it works and I can simply ignore the errors, I want to do this correctly. Any chance anyone else has done this successfully?

Thanks1

Comment: Why do you need to create it within a function?  Would it suffice to just create it once somewhere else, then use it in the function as much as you need?

Comment: I know I should do that, but how do you do that? Wouldn't your code be deployed every time? Causing the same problem? Thanks for your feedback btw!

Comment: You'd just run the code to create the topic once in a local Node.js script. The code you deploy to Cloud Functions then doesn't contain anything about creating a topic, and merely subscribes to it.

Comment: You don't need to redeploy.  A pubsub topic is a persistent resource that sticks around after you've created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#create_a_topic) outside your function, then use it.  Easiest way might be with the [gcloud command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-cli):

```
gcloud pubsub topics create name-of-topic
```